# NodeJS api - "net" on client side

Tags: node.js, tcp

I want to use the api - "net"(https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) on client side. 
My code would look something like:

```
const net = require('net');
const client = net.connect({port: 8124}, () => {
  console.log('connected to server!');
  client.write('hello world!');
});
client.on('end', () => {
 console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

I do *not* want to use websocket, socketio or other libraries out there. 
Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks much!

Comment: What do you mean "on client side"? In the browser?

Comment: @BenFortune Yes in the browser. I will have to use `browserify` or `webpack` to require it and then use it?

Comment: `net` is a native module and there's a very good chance it won't work in the browser.

Comment: Yes I realize so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Net` is not available on the browser since the browser cannot open arbitrary TCP sockets. Few of the options to explore depending upon your case would be `net-browserify` or `http-stream`